# How to show dialog to set image as wallpaper or profile picture in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, android-alertdialog, android-wallpaper

I have a pic inside my app in raw folder. I want to give option to users to set that image as an wallpaper or profile picture. A dialog should popup when the option is selected. Like this: 
[image]

I tried showing this dialog with the following code

```
int resId = R.raw.a_day_without_thinking_mobile;

        Resources resources = this.getResources();
       Uri sendUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + resources.getResourcePackageName(resId) + '/' + resources.getResourceTypeName(resId) + '/' + resources.getResourceEntryName(resId));

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
        intent.setDataAndType(sendUri, "image/jpg");
        intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpg");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set As"));
```

But this showed me a dialog like this:

[image]

I don't want to set image directly as wallpaper instead a dialog should be shown from where user can select whether he/she wants to use the image as wallpaper or profile picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must download image file from raw folder to sd card and then use the sd card file to set the image as wallpaper

```
 int resId = R.raw.a_day_without_thinking_mobile;

String filename = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resId );

                String destfolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() + "/Motivational Quotes";
                createDirIfNotExists(destfolder);

                String destinationPath = destfolder +"/"+ filename + ".jpg";
                File destination = new File(destinationPath);

                InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
                        getResources().getIdentifier(filename,
                                "raw", getPackageName()));





                try {
                    copy2(ins,destination);
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Image Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    File externalFile=new File(destinationPath);
                    Uri sendUri2 = Uri.fromFile(externalFile);
                    Log.d("URI:", sendUri2.toString());

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
                    intent.setDataAndType(sendUri2, "image/jpg");
                    intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpg");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set As"), 200);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

 public void copy2(InputStream src, File dst) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = src;

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
        //InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        addImageGallery(dst);
    }

    private void addImageGallery( File file ) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg"); // setar isso
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    }

    public static boolean createDirIfNotExists(String path) {
        boolean ret = true;

        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e("TravellerLog :: ", "Problem creating Image folder");
                ret = false;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Here is the code that you can use

Answer (score 0):

Remove the put extra from your intent and use the following for data and type

```
intent.setDataAndType(sendUri, "image/*");
```

Comment: Did the change as you said but it doesn't seem to be working. The problem is still the same.